# If $f(x)=x^3-3x^2+x$ and $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$, find $g'(x)$

Tags: derivatives

I found this question in my text book:

> If $f(x)=x^3-3x^2+x$ and $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$, find $g'(x)$

I know that:
$$[f^{-1}(x)]'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$
But, this function is not one to one, so is it right to say that:
$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(g)}=\frac{1}{3g^2-6g+1}$$
? and if so, how to find $g'(x)$ in terms of $x$ ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Write it out as $f(x)=y$, then switch $x\to y$ and solve for $y$, using the solution to the cubic polynomial.

Comment: but $f(x)$ is not strictly monontonouos

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think that's ok.

Comment: Your book is wrong: there is *no* inverse of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of inverse of a function,
$$g(x)=f^{-1}x \Rightarrow f\{g(x)\}=x $$
Hence we have 
$$x=g^3-3g^2+g$$
$$g^3-3g^2+g-x=0$$

By [Cardano's Method](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kkreith/tutorials/sample.lesson/cardano.html), we have that
$$g=1+p+\frac{2}{3p}$$ where $$p=\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{3}}\left[x+1+\sqrt{(1+x)^2-\frac{32}{27}} \right]^\frac{1}{3}$$ since $g$ is a real-valued function.

Now you have to calculate $g'(x)$.